# Javascript Nesting and Recalling Objects

Tags: javascript

I know I can nest objects in objects and recall to them easily example:

```
var ex1 = {
    data1: 1,
    dataOb: {
        data1: 2,
        data2: ex1.data1 + ex1.dataO.data1,
    }
}
```

And I can do `console.log(ex1.dataO.data1)` but I can't recall from `dataOb` to `ex1.data1` example: `data2: ex1.data1 + dataOb.data1` doesn't work, so my question is it possible to recall from DataOb to parental object ex1 ?

Comment: Thanks, but still i can't recall to the ex1.data1 ;<

Comment: duplicate of [Self-references in object literal declarations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616202/self-references-in-object-literal-declarations) - it's the same problem as for unnested objects.

Comment: What are you talking about? You can't do that unless you've defined `ex1` earlier, i.e. you are redefining `ex1`. There is no such thing as "recall".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. At the time that you're defining `data2`, you're still in the middle of defining `ex1`. That is, it doesn't really *exist* yet. You're trying to access it before you've even finished defining it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you question rightly... do you want to use `ex1.data1` in the same sentence you're creating the whole object?

This isn't ever possible!

You want to access to a reference that hasn't been created yet.

It's like doing this:

```
var a = a + 1;
```

How do you set the value of `a` plus 1 if `a` isn't declared already?!

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
var ex1 = {
  data1: 1,
  dataOb: {
    data1: 2,
    data2: 4
  },
  getSum: function () {
    var sum = 0;
    for ( var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++ ) {
      sum += arguments[i];
    }

    return sum;

  }
};

console.log(ex1.getSum(ex1.data1, ex1.dataOb.data1)); // should log 3
```

Comment: Not really clean, but you can even take `ex1.dataOb.data` and make that in a method that returns certain attributes within the object. so from your example, it could be `ex1.dataOb.data2 = function () {return ex1.data1 + ex1.dataOb.data2}`